# lightning:workspaceAPI openSubTab says its not a function

Tags: aura

Any reason why openSubTab is not working ?

[image]

[image]

pls don't mind the workspaceAPI2. i tried to use only 1 instance, its also the same error.

I am able to get enclosingTabId with no problem:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the documentation in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm)

You have a spelling mistake where you are using '**openSubTab()**' instead of '**openSubtab()**'

Comment: got it should be small T. thank you